# begging to + person

Tags: word-usage

Someone told me that "begging to my parents" is wrong because there's this certain rule that says begging to + person is wrong. Is that true? I saw this rule verb + object + to + infinitive, is this under this rule? thanks for the answers. I couldn't find it by just searching.

Comment: You said, "Someone told me that 'begging to my parents' is wrong", but you didn't tell us how 'begging to my parents' was used in the sentence that that someone told you it was wrong. Or did that someone tell you that the string 'begging to my parents' is always wrong (which is unlikely, in my opinion)?

Answer (score 1):

You may: 
"beg your parents for permission to attend the disco",
or you may: 
"beg to attend the disco"
but you can't: 
"beg to your parents for permission to attend the disco".

That's to say: usage allows one to "beg somebody" but not to beg "to somebody".

Comment: It's not that uncommon to see a usage such as "He went begging to his brother."  Of course in this case the "to" clause doesn't operate on "begging" by itself, but rather it operates on "went begging".